# ajax in depended dropdownList in yiii not working

Tags: php, yii

just implemeting depended dropDownList in yii.
its view part is-

```
 echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'standard', $listStandard, array(
            'empty' => 'Select standard',
            'ajax'=>
            array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('scholarship/updateDivision'),
                'update'=>'#updatedDivision',
                //'data'=>array('std'=>'js:this.value'),
            )
            ));

<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('updatedDivision','',array('1'=>'1'),array()); ?>
```

its controller part

```
public function actionUpdateDivision(){
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('updatedDivision','',array('1'=>'hello','2'=>'2'),array());
}
```

here request is not passing to controller.can you find any problem in this code?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/) the controller action must be smth. as following:

```
$data=Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=:parent_id', 
              array(':parent_id'=>(int) $_POST['country_id']));

$data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
foreach($data as $value=>$name)
{
    echo CHtml::tag('option',
               array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
}
```

Obviously, when you update the DOM element in view `id='updatedDivision'` with something also having `id='updatedDivision'` from controller:

> echo CHtml::dropDownList('updatedDivision','',array('1'=>'hello','2'=>'2'),array());

it won't work as desired.

Try this in controller/action:

```
foreach(array('1'=>'hello','2'=>'2') as $value=>$name)
{
    echo CHtml::tag('option',
               array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
}
```

### Update

Also check with web tools (F12, Ctrl+Shift+I) if an ajax XHR is properly formed and response is sent back.